# Windows Docker Trying to run a service

Tags: docker, powershell, dockerfile, containers, windows-server-2019

I'm not sure where this is going wrong at all but I'm new to containers and trying to learn as I go.

I'm trying to containerize a windows service/application and expose a port via a container but can't quite tell how I investigate where it's failing.

I should point out that I'm running this on Server 2019 Datacentre inside VMWare Player.

Dockerfile:

```
# escape=`
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:10.0.17763.2300-amd64

RUN powershell -Command `
    Add-WindowsFeature Web-Server; `
    Invoke-WebRequest -UseBasicParsing -Uri "https://dotnetbinaries.blob.core.windows.net/servicemonitor/2.0.1.10/ServiceMonitor.exe" -OutFile "C:\ServiceMonitor.exe"

EXPOSE 80

ENTRYPOINT ["C:\\ServiceMonitor.exe", "w3svc"]

COPY installer.exe ./
COPY service_start.ps1 ./

RUN powershell -Command `
Start-Process C:\\installer.exe -ArgumentList '-i -nomsg'` -Wait 

CMD ["powershell.exe", "C:\\service_start.ps1"]

EXPOSE 1950
```

Now in theory, this docker file should create an IIS setup along with installing my service.   IIS will run on port 80, my service will communicate on port 1950.

The service_start.ps1 contains:

```
Start-Service -Name "STO Controller"
```

which is the name of the service I'm installing (and works locally)

In PS, I run:

```
docker build -t STOBASE .
```

and the build process is successful.

I then run:

```
docker run -p 1000:80 -p 1001:1950 -dit STOBASE
```

This creates the container and I can see that the IIS portion forces it to stay active

```
docker ps a
```

shows that this is definitely running.

I open a browser and go to http://localhost:1000 and see the IIS splash screen so this part works

http://localhost:1001 should display the splash screen for the service.

MY first thought is that servercore is missing a dependancy as I don't know a lot about the service I'm installing other than it seems to have an integrated webserver due to the fact it serves up a webpage that is accessible on port 1950 from another machine.

Any ideas what I've missed or how I investigate this?

Comment: I should add that I ran: docker inspect -f '{{range.NetworkSettings.Networks}}{{.IPAddress}}{{end}}' angry_blackburn and got the host IP

running http://172.17.14.162:80 gave me IIS and http://172.17.14.162:1950 gave me nothing

Comment: If you launch a shell inside the container with `docker exec -it <container name> powershell.exe` does that give you anything helpful, debugging-wise?